# why does parentNode always come back as undefined yet it is there?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008

I have a set of nested divs:

```
<div style="border:solid 1px #7F9DB9; height:535px; width:285px;" id="div_master">
                <div onmouseover="" id="a" onclick="div_catlist_mouseclick(this)">a</div>
                <div onmouseover="" id="b" onclick="div_catlist_mouseclick(this)">b</div>
                <div onmouseover="" id="c" onclick="div_catlist_mouseclick(this)">c</div>
                <div onmouseover="" id="d" onclick="div_catlist_mouseclick(this)">d</div>
            </div>
```

I am calling the function div_catlist_mouseclick(this) event, on mouseclick:

```
function div_catlist_mouseclick(div) {
        div.style.background = "#316AC5";
        div.style.color = "#fff";

        var x = this.parentNode;
    }
```

Why is it that I can't assign parentNode to x, after I pass that line x is always undefined.  However, if I examine this.parentNode it shows as an object, with 4 child nodes, which is what I expect...

I am trying to get the child nodes so that I can iterate over them and if they are not the selected node, but have been selected before turn their text and background color back to the defaults.  Should be easy right?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `div.parentNode` instead of `this.parentNode`.

Comment: +1 doh!  I stared at this for 2 minutes before I saw it, and then you beat me to it.  No one to blame but myself . . .

Comment: climage - genius, i'm with Patrick 'doh!'  I had been staring at the problem myself for 20 minutes and was thinking I was going mad.  It's Friday, the only excuse I can reasonably come up with.

Comment: Haha it is friday thankfully.  And really you would think that `this` would point to the element that executed the event (link jquery).